# using iterator in prefect task "batching"

Tags: python, parallel-processing, azure-cosmosdb, prefect

I am using [prefect](https://docs.prefect.io/) and defining a [flow](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/flows.html) to insert documents with cosmos db.

The problem is the [query_items()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.container.containerproxy?view=azure-python#query-items-query--parameters-none--partition-key-none--enable-cross-partition-query-none--max-item-count-none--enable-scan-in-query-none--populate-query-metrics-none----kwargs-) call is an iterable, and for large containers, there would be no way to hold all entries in memory.

I believe my problem could be reduced to:

- `given an iterator, how can I create batches to be processed (mapped) in a prefect flow?`

Example:

```py
def big_iterable_function_i_cannot_change():
    yield from range(1000000) # some large amount of work

@task
def some_prefect_batching_magic(x):
    # magic code here
    pass


with Flow("needs-to-be-batched"):
    some_prefect_batching_magic.map(big_iterable_function_i_cannot_change())
```

The above code, or something like it will give me an error:

```
prefect.FlowRunner | Flow run FAILED: some reference tasks failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are not defining `big_iterable_function_i_cannot_change` as a `task`. `prefect` does not actually execute a `flow` directly.  The `flow` is used to make a `schedule`, (in `dask` parlance) -- Which is then used to execute the flow, (as far as I understand).  Parallelization in `prefect` only happens when it is used with the [dask executor](https://docs.prefect.io/api/latest/executors.html).

Here is my take on your `flow`.  But if you cannot add the task decorator to `big_iterable_function_i_cannot_change` into a `task`, wrap it in a task.   Finally - Not sure you can pass a generator to a mapped task.

```
import prefect
from prefect import Flow, Parameter, task

@task
def big_iterable_function_i_cannot_change():
    return range(5) # some large amount of work

@task
def some_prefect_batching_magic(x):
    # magic code here
    pass


with Flow("needs-to-be-batched") as flow:
    itter_res = big_iterable_function_i_cannot_change()
    post_process_res = some_prefect_batching_magic.map(itter_res)

flow.visualize()
state = flow.run()


flow.visualize(flow_state=state)
```

Comment: You cannot pass generators https://docs.prefect.io/core/advanced_tutorials/task-guide.html#task-inputs-and-outputs